# How to make for loop in node.js and mongoDB run synchronously

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, for-loop

This is my first time with Node.js, and I'm having an issue with it.

I'm getting some data from an API, and I'm storing them on a array.

Then, I'm doing some MongoDB's query to know if the data that I have on that array are in the database.

I thought to use a for loop for every occurrence of array, but when I try to call MongoDB, for loop keep going to increase the counter immediately, without waiting the end of query and relative response, and I get data only for the last occurrence (repeatedly).

There's a part of my code, and with this I get always the 'result' on console relative at the last occurrence (for example, if I expect something like '1, 2, 3, 4, 5', I have '5 5 5 5 5')

How can I do to be sure that for loop works on the right way?

Thanks for help.

```
for ( counter = 0; counter < array.lenght; counter ++) {

    MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {

       var query = { name: array[counter] };

       db.collection("collectionName").find(query).toArray(function (err, result) {

           // Check if 'query' value exist in the database, if yes do some stuff, otherwise do others stuff
           console.log(result); 


    }
)
```

EDIT: Just to let everyone know, the code finally works. 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried using the `await` keyword yet?

Comment: Check the [async / await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) as suggested by @UghThatGuyAgain

Comment: However, `await` in a loop is not always right: Be sure you really want to force sequential execution. Often, when inside a loop statement, the individual steps are independent of one another. If it's parallelizable instead create an array of promsies and `await Promise.all(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the below code. Let me know if it worked or not.

```
let fun = async function () {
    for (var counter = 0; counter < array.length; counter++) {
        await MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
            var query = { name: array[counter] };
            db.collection("collectionName").find(query).toArray(function (err, result) {
                // Check if 'query' value exist in the database, if yes do some stuff, otherwise do others stuff
                console.log(result);
            })
        })
    }
}

fun();
```

Comment: Hi folks, thanks for you help. It doesn't work, the issue remains always the same, for loop keeping increase counter variable without waiting for the Mongo's query's answer.

Comment: I tried with your update, but it doesn't work, the problem is always the same. Thanks anyway for your help.

Comment: Already did it, I get "SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" relative to db.collection

Comment: Even if I put for loop into the connection, the result is always the same. It always shows on console the result of the query relative to the last item of the array.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is async execution is waiting until the end of the for to start with the async methods, and at that moment counter has the maximum value for all the executions. 
A solution is to put all the content of the for in a different function and call it with the parameters needed. With this you create a new closure and keep the value of the variables.

```
var doSomething = function(loopValue) {
    MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
        var query = { name: loopValue };
        db.collection("collectionName").find(query).toArray(function (err, result) {
            // Check if 'query' value exist in the database, if yes do some stuff, otherwise do others stuff
            console.log(result); 
        }
    }
}

for (let counter = 0; counter < array.length; counter ++) {
    doSomething(array[counter]);
)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. Could you please explain it? I understand the concept, but I want to be sure about what I should do for it..

Comment: I edited the answer with the code example. Maybe you need to pass other parameters, but it depends on the context. Hope it helps

Comment: It doesn't work, but thanks for help in any case ;-)

Comment: I didn't get any error, because the code is wrote good. I get alway the result for the last item of the array (if array.lenght is 5, I get for five times the answer for array[5])

Comment: With these 2 things work to me:
-   lenght   =>   length
-   for ( counter      =>     for ( let counter

Comment: the word "lenght" is misspelled. It should be "length"
and put "let" before  "counter = 0" in the for declaration